# Check that the map $F:X\times Y\rightarrow Y \times X$, defined by $(x,y) \rightarrowtail (y,x)$ is bijective.

Tags: functions

Check that the map $F:X\times Y\rightarrow Y \times X$, defined by $(x,y) \rightarrowtail (y,x)$ is bijective. Describe the relationship between mutually inverse maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $f^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$.

Question is from book "Mathematical Analysis" by Zorich, chapter 1.3 - Function, question 5d.

My attempt at a proof:
First, let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$.

Then, to show that f is injective, we note that $g \circ f = id_X$, which implies that g is the left inverse of f, hence f is injective.

To show that f is surjective, we note that $f \circ g = id_Y$. So g is the right inverse of f, hence f is surjective. Hence f is bijective and g = $f^{-1}$, which is bijective too. Composition of bijective functions is bijective, so $g \circ f = F:X\times Y\rightarrow Y \times X$ is bijective.

Second part of the question is a bit unclear to me though. The relationship between graphs of f and $f^{-1}$ is obviously, as it is stated in the actual question, is that they are mutually inverse functions. However, I am not sure what else I can say regarding that. The definition of a graph of function is {$(x,y) \in X \times Y | y = f(x)$}. So for the inverse it would be {$(y,x) \in Y \times X | x = f(y)$}. But just stating the definitions doesn't seem like a sufficient answer.

Would greatly appreciate any corrections in both logic and notation. In particular, I am very not sure that I'm allowed to say that $g \circ f = id_X$ in the function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, as I defined it, which is what my whole argument is based on.

Comment: Although it is obvious, you should define $g$ in your proof.

Comment: Also, you seem to prove that $f$ is bijective, rather than $F$.

Comment: @DanDan0101 But if f is bijective, then g, its inverse, is also bijective? So their composition is bijective.

Comment: @JohnDoe But $F$ is not their composition, as I said. We don't even know what "they" are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make too much sense. You haven't defined $g$! Or $f$. You claim $F=g\circ f$ but if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$, then $g\circ f:X\to X$ whereas $F:X\times Y\to Y\times X$. So there is a serious domain and codomain error (also, you claim $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$, whatever $g,f$ are... and $F$ is not the identity).

For the second part, try to relate the graphs of $f,f^{-1}$ with the function $F$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you give me a hint on what I should start with to rewrite my proof? And if any parts of my existing proof could be used?

Comment: @JohnDoe With respect, I don't think any of what you wrote can be used: it is founded on these undefined "$f,g$". You want to show $F$ is bijective. Can you write down an inverse to $F$? Hopefully. Or, can you check that: $F$ injects and: $F$ surjects? Try to do direct checks. Mistakes newcomers sometimes make is get lost in repeating definitions, which you seemed to do in this case

Comment: Hello again! Well, F^-1 can be defined as a function from Y×X to X×Y, sending (y,x) to (x,y). Then F^-1 composed with F is a function from X×Y to X×Y, so F composed with F^-1 gives Id_X×Y, (since it sends (x,y) to (x,y) ) hence F^-1 is the left inverse of F, and so F is injective. Is that better, or am I making the same mistake?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yeah that's right. $(y,x)\mapsto(x,y)$ is an inverse of $F$.

Comment: Thank you! So to answer the original question, would my comment above suffice to prove that F is injective? And would composing F with F^-1 to get Id_YxX be ok to show that F^-1 is the right inverse of F, and hence F is surjective? And also sorry for the possibly stupid question, but I'm still not sure how to relate f, f^-1 with F... Obviously f acts only on the domain of F, taking some x to some y, hence graph of f is a subset of XxY. Likewise f^-1 acts on the range of F, taking some y to some x, hence it's graph is a subset of YxX. Is that enough of a connection? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @JohnDoe (1) Yes, to show $F$ has an inverse suffices to show it is injective, and also surjective, so bijective. (2) Yes, as long as you actually check the composite is the identity. (3) The connection is that $F(\text{something})=\text{something else}$ where the 'something's are related to the graphs

Comment: Ok, thanks again for you time!